# Run FastAPI server with UVICORN --reload exits with exception module '_multiprocessing' has no attribute 'sem_unlink'

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

In a ubuntu 18.04 docker container, I use pyenv to install python 3.8.18, and then use virtualenvwrapper to create a virtualenv, then install fastapi with:

python3 -m pip install fastapi[all]

Then run a FastAPI app with command like:

`uvicorn --port 5901 --reload cicd.server:app`

In the first instance of such container, all worked well.

Then I try to redo the same on another container, but it failed to start with the following call stack.

Without `--reload` option the server can start without problem.

How to fix this issue? Thanks.

```
$ uvicorn --port 5901 cicd.server:app --reload
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:5901 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [62954] using WatchFiles
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 416, in main
    run(
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 582, in run
    ChangeReload(config, target=server.run, sockets=[sock]).run()
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/supervisors/basereload.py", line 49, in run
    self.startup()
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/envs/cicd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/supervisors/basereload.py", line 85, in startup
    self.process.start()
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 39, in _launch
    from . import resource_tracker
  File "/home/cicd/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py", line 41, in <module>
    'semaphore': _multiprocessing.sem_unlink,
AttributeError: module '_multiprocessing' has no attribute 'sem_unlink'
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am facing the same issue